# Jquery how to replace a data object on max-width ( flickity )

Tags: jquery, media, flickity

i'm new here and this is my first question.

I have some galleries with flickity library in a simple page, when is desktop every gallery has 3 pictures per dot sliding every 3 seconds and when the res is set to smartphone the gallery viewport should switches to 1 picture per dot.
So here is the html code:

```
<div class="carousel flick" data-flickity='{ "cellAlign": "left", "contain": true, "groupCells": 3, "autoPlay": true, "wrapAround": true, "prevNextButtons": false }'></div>
```

as you can see there is an object called groupCells 3, that mean, that the gallery will switch 3 cells per time, but if i go in smartphone mode, i need to say to the data attr that groupCells must be 1 when max width is set to 991px

So here is my query:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
if (viewportWidth < 991) {
        $( ".flick" ).data( "flickity" ).groupCells === "1";
}
```

});

Of course, won't work.

What's wrong with it?

Thanks for you support!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
  var json = $( ".flick" ).data( "flickity" );
  if (viewportWidth < 991) {
    json.groupCells = 1;
    $( ".flick" ).data( "flickity" , json);

  } else {
    json.groupCells = 3;
    $( ".flick" ).data( "flickity" , json);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot TheBrutalX !! :D I hope this will help someone esle!!
I talked with him directly and we solved this problem in another better way.
This first post works perfectly but the script should be wrote at the end of the html to work properly.

Then, here his solution:

```
<div class="carousel flick"></div>
```

Jquery to start the gallery and resize placed at the end of the html to work properly when resized:

```
 var slider_setting = {
            cellAlign: 'left',
              contain: true,
              groupCells: 3,
              autoPlay: true,
              wrapAround: true,
              prevNextButtons: false
        };
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".flick").each(function(){
            var viewportWidth = $(window).width()
            if (viewportWidth < 991) {
              slider_setting.groupCells = 1;
            } else {
                slider_setting.groupCells = 3;
            }
            $(this).flickity(slider_setting);
        });
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
        if (viewportWidth < 991) {
          slider_setting.groupCells = 1;
        } else {
            slider_setting.groupCells = 3;
        }
        $(".flick").each(function(){
            $(this).flickity('destroy');
            $(this).flickity(slider_setting);
        });
    });
```

Thank you very much TheBrutalx!